# PHP - Guzzle Strange trouble

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using last version of PGP Guzzle HTTP... Very simple test done :

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();
    $res = $client->post('https://MYAPI/cards/XXX/credit',[
        'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Token MYTOKEN'],
        'json' => [
            "amount" => 10,
            "reason" => "Because"
        ]
    ]);
    var_dump($res);
```

returned a Exception:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException : Client error: `POST 
https://MYAPI/cards/XXX/credit` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed` 
response:
{"detail":"Méthode \"GET\" non autorisée."}
```

Any idea ? the REST API server I am calling is made with Django DRF. But this is nonsense to think it might be incompatible....

Thanxs for any idea.

Comment: Try to debug request lifecycle in django

Answer (score 1):

You get very clear error that the server doesn't accept POST request. I don't know, is it right or not. If have control over the server also, you check the code there, maybe it's just a bug in it.

Basically you cannot talk about compatibility or incompatibility, because it's just simple HTTP and it works. You can have an issue either in communications between you and the server developers or a bug in the server.

Comment: Well the question was not about any compatibility, more for some idea about any configuration I may miss in Guzzle http client class.

Comment: It's all OK with your code. Take a look at the server, it just says that POST requests are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was neither Guzzle nor DRF whiche failed.... only one parameter in DRF urls that does not accept trailing / in rest entry points....

simply adding / after the credit url and everything worked fine....

Strange behaviour somehow for DRF to display this kind of misleading error message .